# tail bound of the deviation from sum of functions of random variables to its expectation value

Tags: probability, error-propagation, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

I am struggling at an error propagation recently and I do not know what tools can be used in this problem. Explicitly my problem can be represented as following:

I have expression
$$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_{i=1}^N\left[f(x_i+\epsilon_i)-f(x_i)\right]\right|$$
where $\epsilon_i$ is i.i.d with expectation $\bar{\epsilon_i}=\mu$ and variance $var(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^2$ and $f(\cdot)$ is some kind of function.

Is there any method I can find the tail bound of $\varepsilon$ for universal function $f(\cdot)$, or for some specific function, e.g: $f(x)=e^{-ax}$ or $f(x)=ax^2$?

==========================================

here is some result I found:

for $f(x)=e^{-ax}$
$$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_{i=1}^N\left[f(x_i+\epsilon_i)-f(x_i)\right]\right|\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\left|e^{-a\epsilon_i}-1\right|$$

since $\epsilon_i$ is i.i.d, so $X_i=\left|e^{-a\epsilon_i}-1\right|$ is also i.i.d.

use central limit theorem we can find a tail bound of $\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\left|e^{-a\epsilon_i}-1\right|$, so we can give a tail bound on $\varepsilon$.

but this result is somehow a little trivial because the tail bound is not zero-centric, which means $\varepsilon$ has a significant probability to be finite.

so is there other result of this problem?

Comment: It seems difficult to get vanishing error, i.e., $\epsilon = o(1)$ with such a general setup. On other hand, getting an upper bound of $\epsilon = O(1)$ seems feasible for the quadratic function. Would that suffice for your purpose? In the current form, the question is very open-ended.

Comment: ah yeah, this current form might be very loose. actually I found that if some method of enlarging and reducing is used then this problem can  be slightly changed and might be easier to solve. details is already added in the question. but I am afraid this result is also too loose to be useful.

Comment: @BenjaminJiang, it looks like in one formula you forgot a term, here is the right version:  $$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_{i=1}^N\left[f(x_i+\epsilon_i)-f(x_i)\right]\right|\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\left|e^{-a\epsilon_i}-1\right| e^{-ax_i}.$$ Maybe you implied that $a \ge 0$ and $x_i \ge 0$.

Comment: @Botnakov N ah sorry it is my negligence, in my setting, $a>0$ and $0<x<1$ which is a probability, so I can get this result. but generally speaking, yeah, this is not valid and the factor must be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is a  Lipschitz function with constant $c$. For example, $sin (bx), \frac1{1+x^2}$.

In this case $$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_{i=1}^N\left[f(x_i+\epsilon_i)-f(x_i)\right]\right| \le \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N|f(x_i+\epsilon_i)-f(x_i)| \le c \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N|\epsilon_i| }{N}.$$

$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N|\epsilon_i| }{N} \to E|\epsilon_1|$ a.s. and is asymptotically normal.

As $x_i$ are all distinct and $f$ is arbitrary, then we don't have any reason to wait that errors will compensate each other.

In special case $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots$ we may put $Y_i = f(x_i+\epsilon_i)-f(x_i)$ and use CLT for $Y_i$.

Comment: thanks your helpful thought. yeah you are right, if only consider a general function, Lipschitz property may be a reasonable assumption and results in a suitable bound. however, in my perspective I think that functions with only Lipschitz property might lead to a somehow weak bound, isn't it? I do not know weather there exist some other tools can be used? or, if we consider a specific function, e.g. $f(x)=e^{-ax}$, do you know some tools might be helpful?

Comment: @BenjaminJiang Put $Y_i = f(x_i + \epsilon_i) - f(x_i)$. If we want to have the situation, when "errors" $\epsilon_i$ compensate each other, we should have such $f$ that CLT for $Y_i$ works. Is it your case?

Comment: yeah I think this problem again and conclude that there may not exist general tight bound. so maybe the specification of function $f(x)$ is necessary. in that case, your suggestion of Lipschitz property is really helpful. thank you again.

Comment: @BenjaminJiang, you are welcome!